# Is there a way to run custom js code on the selected text in VScode? To make a markdown Table of Contents

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, markdown

I've been working with some markdown docs lately. When I compose a document, I usually want links to every part of the document at the very top. That means I should go through the document, copy all heading titles, then enclose them in special syntax:

```
 * [Chapter One](#chapter-one)
 * [Chapter Two](#chapter-two)
 * [Chapter Three](#chapter-three)
 * [Subchapter One](#subchapter-one)
 * [Subchapter Two](#subchapter-two)
```

Those links (#chapter-three) are a pain to write though because I have to copy the heading, replace all spaces with hyphens, remove capitalization, and add a '#' symbol. This can be easily achieved with JavaScript:

```js
'#'+'Chapter One'.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');

//#chapter-one
```

So I've been using Chrome terminal to run this script for every heading, and paste the result into VSCode.

What I'd like to do is select some text in VScode, run this code on it (preferably add a key binding or a button for easy access), and place the result in the clipboard.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe you try this ?  [md-toc](https://github.com/ekalinin/github-markdown-toc)

Comment: Well, this works wonders for my particular use-case, thanks! The only downside is, I use git bash as my default shell, and md-toc requires wget to install.

All VSCode TOC plugins don't cut it either.

It should be possible to run js from command palette or with a key combination, right?

Comment: I think you have to make your own small extension for this. [VS extension docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)

Comment: Use Map-Replace extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Yukai.map-replace-js

Comment: Map-Replace is just what the doctor ordered! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy way to do what you want with a single keybinding.  You will need to install the [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview) extension (that I wrote).  Then make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+f",                  // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "description": "get headers, make links",
  "args": {

    "find": "(?<=^###? )(.*)$",
    
    "run": [
      "$${",
        "const headers = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selections;",
        "let str = '';",

        "headers.forEach(header => {",
          "const selectedHeader = document.getText(header);",
          "str += `* [${selectedHeader}](#${selectedHeader.toLocaleLowerCase().split(' ').join('-')})\\n`;",
        "});",

        "str = str.slice(0, -1);",    // remove last \n from str
        "vscode.env.clipboard.writeText(str);",
      "}$$"
    ],

    "isRegex": true,
    "postCommands": [
      "cursorTop", 
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",  
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter", 
      "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
    ]
  }
}
```

First it finds and selects all these headers `(?<=^###? )(.*)$` - so all header with `##` or more header indicators.

Then it uses those selections in the `run` section to construct a newLine-separated list of links and copy the result to the clipboard.

If you just want it in the clipboard for usage anywhere you could stop there but in the demo code I added `postCommands` so that it will go to the top of the file and insert the result under the `# Top Header` (assuming it is on the first line of the file).

The extension allows you to run vscode extension api code, like `document.getText(someRange)` in the `run` or `replace` fields.

[image: demo of making a markdown table of contents keybinding command]

> Note: I used your code for converting to a link - this may need to be modified to handle accented characters or other special use cases.

> Also, it would be very easy to modify this to just handle the current selection and write the result to the clipboard: get rid of the `find` and `postCommands` arguments and add `"restrictFind": "line"` as an arg.